# Текст внутри контейнера

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Я делаю `<v-card>` во vuetify и хочу сделать так, чтобы текст у меня был ограничен. Т.е. если текста оказывается слишком много, нужно, чтобы он не улетал за пределы контейнера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочется, чтобы было примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из способов сделать это на css:

```
overflow: hidden
text-overflow: ellipsis
white-space: nowrap
```

К сожалению, это не совсем то, что нужно. Получается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данный пример можно доделать, чтобы работало так, как нужно. Для этого следует использовать [мультилайн](http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/).

Проблема была побеждена с помощью фунции:

```
 cut(text) {
     if (text.length > this.max_length_description) {
         return text.slice(0, this.max_length_description) + '...'
     }
     return text;
 },


 <v-card-text
     class="custom-debug"
     style="
        height: 120px;
     "
 >
     {{ cut(course.short_description) }}
 </v-card-text>
```

Очевидно, это не самое изящное решение, так как при смене шрифта, придётся менять 
`max_length_description`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]